# How can I configure watchman to watch multiple fs roots?

Tags: watchman

Suppose for instance that I have two directories `src` and `test` and I want to run a command when a file changes in either of those trees. I don't want to watch their parent directory since `src` and `test` have siblings which I don't want to watch.

Comment: Please add more context; is the parent of these two directories a git or hg repo?  Why don't you want to watch that dir? Are there other siblings that are very large or change very frequently (if so, how many files and how frequently)?  Knowing the answers to these will help give the best advice

Comment: Right so imagine a package manager (in this case npm) puts a bunch of stuff (186M) in a sibling (`/node_modules`) that almost never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I think you're anticipating performance problems with `node_modules`.  It may not be be a problem in practice (I'll refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29654359/149111 for some context; the number of files and dirs impacts performance much more than the combined size of those files), so I'd suggest just watching the common root dir and see if you end up encountering warnings about recrawls.

If you do hit problems with recrawls, then the recommendation is to use the `ignore_dirs` configuration option.

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#ignore_dirs has more information on this, but the TL;DR is that you can create a `.watchmanconfig` file in the common root dir with these contents:

```
{
   "ignore_dirs": ["node_modules"]
}
```

This causes the watcher not to recurse into the `node_modules` dir.

Comment: Thanks so much! Super helpful :)